# template argument loses a lvalue reference, if not used directly

Tags: c++, templates, reference, c++11

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<typename T_orig> void f(T_orig& a){
    a=5;
}


template<typename T_orig, typename T=T_orig&> void g(T a){
    a=8;
}

int main() {
    int b=3;
    f<decltype(b)>(b);
    cout<<b<<endl;
    g<decltype(b)>(b);
    cout<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
5
5
```

Can somebody explain to me why in the second version the `&` is lost?

Comment: Btw, `ternary_op` looks a lot like `std::conditional`.

Comment: This is a simplified version, it's basically the same: http://ideone.com/9DSsfb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that type deduction takes priority over defaulted function template parameters. Therefore you get the `T` parameter deduced and `T` never deduces to a reference.

You can prevent this by making the type [not deducible](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=df15a53aeeb6f0f26c9088a1effe8873). A generic identity type trait can do this.

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
using NotDeducible = typename identity<T>::type;

template<typename T_orig, typename T=typename target<T_orig>::T>
void g(NotDeducible<T> a) { // blah
```

Or, in this particular case, you can simply get rid of the template parameter altogether.

```
template<typename T_orig> void g(typename target<T_orig>::T a)
```